# Google Navigation when launched behind keyguard

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent, android-service, android-wake-lock

I'm using an intent to start google navigation from my service. My service has a partial wakelock and this works fine when the screen is on. But if I turn off the screen (partial wake lock keeps cpu running), then google navigation will open, but it won't start navigating. Is there a better solution then turning on the screen temporarily? Also why is there this behavior?

Intent:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=" + latlong));
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
    | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED
    | Intent.FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND);
context.startActivity(i);
```

Wakelock(don't worry I'm releasing it later...):

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context
    .getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "Carma");
wakeLock.acquire();
```

Thank you in advance!

**EDIT:**

Through further research it seems that Google Navigation is having a problem with being launched from behind the keyguard... My current solution is to wake up the device and disable the keyguard temporarily to launch the intent. But this is far from an optimal solution...

Comment: can't you prevent device to sleep?

Comment: For reference please look at the website for my app: Carma.RSenApps.com, I want the app to be usable even when the screen is on...